# FirebaseError: [code=unknown]: Fetching auth token failed: Cannot redefine property: refreshToken

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

Simple application where I configure the firebase ...

```
import * as firebase from "firebase/app";
import 'firebase/auth';

const app = firebase.initializeApp(FIREBASE_CONFIG);
firebase.setLogLevel('debug');
app.auth().useDeviceLanguage();
app.auth().settings.appVerificationDisabledForTesting = __DEVELOPMENT__;
```

Then I configure the database

```
import 'firebase/firestore';
const database = app.firestore();
    database.settings({
        host: 'localhost:8080',
        ssl: true,
    });
```

With anonymous user

```
const handleAuthStateChanged = (user) => {
    if (!user) {
        firebase.auth().signInAnonymously();
    }
}
app.auth().onAuthStateChanged(handleAuthStateChanged)
```

And I tried to get some data

```
database.collection('events').doc(eventId).withConverter(eventConverter).get();
```

But I'm receiving this error

> @firebase/firestore: Firestore (7.15.0): FirestoreClient Initializing. user=
> @firebase/firestore: Firestore (7.15.0): MemoryPersistence Starting transaction: Get next mutation batch
> @firebase/firestore: Firestore (7.15.0): MemoryPersistence Starting transaction: Allocate target
> @firebase/firestore: Firestore (7.15.0): MemoryPersistence Starting transaction: Execute query
> @firebase/firestore: Firestore (7.15.0): IndexFreeQueryEngine Using full collection scan to execute query: Query(target=Target(events/1, orderBy: [**name** (asc)]); limitType=F)
> @firebase/firestore: Firestore (7.15.0): PersistentStream close with error: FirebaseError: [code=unknown]: Fetching auth token failed: Cannot redefine property: refreshToken
>
> @firebase/firestore: Firestore (7.15.0): Could not reach Cloud Firestore backend. Connection failed 1 times. Most recent error: FirebaseError: [code=unknown]: Fetching auth token failed: Cannot redefine property: refreshToken
>
> This typically indicates that your device does not have a healthy Internet connection at the moment. The client will operate in offline mode until it is able to successfully connect to the backend.

and

> FirebaseError: Failed to get document because the client is offline.

---

### Works once I publish

If you go to .. https://nps-event.ridermansb.dev/event/1 you will see that it's working.

But locally is not working

**Full source code here**

https://github.com/Ridermansb/nps-event

Comment: Any updates on this question? I am in this exact spot.

Answer (score 1):

Firebase allows users to Implement its Authentication SDK to your [sign in method](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth#key_capabilities). By reviewing your codes, I can see that Firebase Authentication [anonymous signin](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/anonymous-auth#authenticate-with-firebase-anonymously) method has been used here. It seems to be missing the error handling method in the method. You can refer to [signInAonymously method](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.Auth#signinanonymously) documentation to add the error handling method to get more details about the error.

Comment: The authentication works well (no errors throw ) , this error occurs  when `database.collection('events').doc(eventId) .withConverter(eventConverter).get();`

Answer (score 0):

When it works online, but not locally you could set the service account that is used online to work locally to.

To do so:

- In google cloud console download a service account key
- set your `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` environment variable to the location of that file.
- Try again

See more details on https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/getting-started